# Attempting to compare numbers that are strings

Tags: swift

I am trying to compare the value of two playing cards to determine if a card is larger or smaller than the other. I was able to do it in python using classes but I wish to be able to do it in Swift.

The `i.number` returns "Four" instead of 4 so it is not able to compare because it is a string. The error that appears is:

> value of type 'Int' has no member 'number'

```
if firstNine[0.number] > stack[0.number] {  
             ^ ~~~~~~
```

```swift
import UIKit

enum Number: Int {
    case Two = 2
    case Three = 3
    case Four = 4
    case Five = 5
    case Six = 6
    case Seven = 7
    case Eight = 8
    case Nine = 9
    case Ten = 10
    case Jack = 11
    case Queen = 12
    case King = 13
    case Ace = 14

    static var randomNumber: Number {
        return [Two , Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace][Int(arc4random_uniform(13))]

    }
}

enum Suit: String {
    case Spades = "spades"
    case Hearts = "hearts"
    case Diamonds = "diamonds"
    case Clubs = "clubs"

    static var randomSuit: Suit {
        return [Spades, Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs][Int(arc4random_uniform(4))]
    }
}

struct Card: CustomStringConvertible, Equatable {
    let number: Number
    let suit: Suit

    var description: String {
        return "\(number.rawValue) of \(suit.rawValue)"
    }

    static var randomCard: Card {
        return Card(number: Number.randomNumber, suit: Suit.randomSuit)
    }

    static func randomCards(count: Int) -> [Card] {
        guard count > 0 else {
            return []
        }
        guard count <= 52 else {
            fatalError("There only are 52 unique cards.")
        }
        let cards = randomCards(count: count - 1)
        while true {
            let card = randomCard
            if !cards.contains(card) {
                return cards + [card]
            }
        }
    }
}

func == (left: Card, right: Card) -> Bool {
    return left.number == right.number && left.suit == right.suit
}

let randomCards = Card.randomCards(count: 52)

var deck: [Card] = []
var firstNine: [Card] = []
var stack: [Card] = []




for i in randomCards {
    deck.append(i)
}

for i in 0...9 {
    firstNine.append(deck[i])

}

for i in 10...51 {
    stack.append(deck[i])
}


for i in firstNine {
    print(i.number)
}

for i in stack {
    print(i.number)
}


if firstNine[0.number] > stack[0.number] {
    print ("Lower")
    print (firstNine[0])
}
else {
    print ("wrong")
}
```

Comment: `firstNine[0].number`.

Comment: Use `if firstNine[0].number > stack[0].number {`

Comment: Thank you! it worked with firstNine[0].number.rawValue

Comment: @ThomasHerz better to make your card conform to Comparable. Btw why would you need to compare the suite as well when checking if equatable? Suite doesn’t matter when comparing the card value

Comment: I would also just shuffle the whole deck and get a slice of the resulting array

Comment: Unrelated but your way to create the random Number is outdated. Make the enum conform to `CaseInterable` and use the `random` API of `Collection`: `static var randomNumber: Number {   return allCases.randomElement()! }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you introduce a `Deck` struct to wrap the array of `Card`s.  You can also make `Card` conform to `Comparable`.

Something like:

```
enum Number: Int, CaseIterable {
    case two = 2
    case three = 3
    case four = 4
    case five = 5
    case six = 6
    case seven = 7
    case eight = 8
    case nine = 9
    case ten = 10
    case jack = 11
    case queen = 12
    case king = 13
    case ace = 14

    static func random() -> Number {
        return Number.allCases.randomElement()!
    }
}

enum Suit: String, CaseIterable {
    case spades = "spades"
    case hearts = "hearts"
    case diamonds = "diamonds"
    case clubs = "clubs"

    static func random() -> Suit {
        return Suit.allCases.randomElement()!
    }
}

struct Card: CustomStringConvertible, Equatable, Comparable {

    let number: Number
    let suit: Suit

    var description: String {
        return "\(number) of \(suit)"
    }

    static func == (left: Card, right: Card) -> Bool {
        return left.number == right.number && left.suit == right.suit
    }

    static func < (lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
        return lhs.number.rawValue < rhs.number.rawValue
    }
}

struct Deck {

    let cards: [Card]

    init() {

        var cards = [Card]()
        for suit in Suit.allCases {
            for value in Number.allCases {
                cards.append(Card(number: value, suit: suit))
            }
        }

        self.cards = cards
    }

    private init(cards: [Card]) {
        self.cards = cards
    }

    func shuffled() -> Deck {
        return Deck(cards: self.cards.shuffled())
    }

    func cut(size: Int) -> (Deck,Deck) {
        if size < 1 {
            return (Deck(cards: []),self)
        }

        if size > self.cards.count {
            return (self,Deck(cards:[]))
        }

        return (Deck(cards: Array(self.cards[..<size])),Deck(cards: Array(self.cards[size...])))
    }
}

let randomCards = Deck().shuffled()


let cut = randomCards.cut(size: 9)
let firstNine = cut.0
let remainder = cut.1

print(firstNine.cards[0])
print(remainder.cards[0])

if firstNine.cards[0] > remainder.cards[0] {
    print("Higher")
} else {
    print("Not higher")
}
```

Comment: rawalue is redundant when used in a String interpolation

Comment: True; I just copied that from the OP.  In the case of `Number` it gives a slightly different output ("Four" vs "4"), I guess it depends what they want.

Answer (score 2):

```
enum Number: Int, CaseIterable, Comparable {
    case two = 2, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king, ace
}

enum Suit: String, CaseIterable {
    case spades, hearts, diamonds, clubs
}

extension CaseIterable {
    static var random: Self.AllCases.Element {
        return Self.allCases.randomElement()!
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Card {
    static var randomCard: Card {
        return .init(number: .random, suit: .random)
    }
}

struct Card: CustomStringConvertible, Equatable, Comparable {
    let number: Number
    let suit: Suit
    var description: String {
        return "\(number) of \(suit)"
    }
}
extension Number {
    static func == (left: Number, right: Number) -> Bool {
        return left.rawValue == right.rawValue
    }
    static func < (left: Number, right: Number) -> Bool {
        return left.rawValue < right.rawValue
    }
}
extension Card {
    static func == (left: Card, right: Card) -> Bool {
        return left.number == right.number
    }
    static func < (left: Card, right: Card) -> Bool {
        return left.number < right.number
    }
    static let deck: [Card] = Suit.allCases.map { suit -> [Card] in
        Number.allCases.map { number -> Card in
            .init(number: number, suit: suit)
        }
    }.flatMap({$0})
}
```

---

```
let shuffledDeck = Card.deck.shuffled()
let firstNine = shuffledDeck.prefix(9)

for card in firstNine {
    print(card)
}

for card in shuffledDeck {
    print(card)
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if only comparing the `number` of a card is correct - I guess it depends on the semantics that the OP wants.  Are two cards "equal" if they have the same value or do they also need to be of the same suit?

Comment: @Paulw11 this depends on the purpose when comparing it. He can also pass a predicate where he can match both if he needs to find the index of the card in the collection

Comment: Yes, I suspect that the struct needs some additional comparison functions beyond the operators; For example a King and a Jack both have a face value of 10 in a game like 21, but a King is > Jack in Poker (And an Ace can be 1 or 11...)